# Was Lucius Malfoy actually going to kill Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

At the end of the film version of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Harry tricks Lucius Malfoy into giving Dobby a sock. Since this means that his household servant is no longer under his control, this understandably causes Lucius some annoyance. He pulls out his wand and begins to incant a spell

> "Avada..."

before Dobby steps in and zaps him.

[Avada Kedavra](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Killing_Curse) is known as the 'killing curse'. Using it supposedly results in your immediate transfer to Azkaban for a life sentence.

**Was Lucius *seriously* about to kill a twelve year old child with an unforgivable curse, directly outside the Headmaster's office, with witnesses around?**

[image: Lucius Malfoy with an expression of hatred, raising his wand to cast a spell]

Comment: Chris Columbus dun' goofed. Or maybe it was aimed at Dobby.

Comment: Out-of-universe: apparently Jason Isaacs was just told to make up a curse for this scene, and pulled this one off the top of his head. Sources of varying degrees of dubiousness claim he said this in an interview, but nobody can produce a link.

Comment: He would've gotten away with it, too, if it wasn't for that meddling elf.

Comment: @MajorStackings - "Avada...Kittens". The kitten curse.

Comment: That is a heck of a face in that frame.  He looks like he was auditioning for Peter Pettigrew.

Comment: He's normally cold and calculating, but given what happened in the scene just before, and how much he hates Harry, and how arrogant the little kid was when he tricked Malfoy, and so on, I don't think it's too out-of-character for him to lose his temper. Besides, Voldemort would have been thrilled when he returned, even if Malfoy had been punished.

Comment: It's worth noting that at that point in the story, the "Avada Kedavra" curse had not yet been introduced.

Comment: If you watch the movie with the cc on, it says Lucius says "vera". Maybe he was going to use Vera Verto??

Comment: @KeithThompson That doesn't mean that, in-universe, no one knew about it.

Comment: @forest Sure, I assume it would be well known. Dobby would have known about it. Harry probably didn't yet, but that wouldn't have mattered if Dobby hadn't stopped Lucius.

Comment: @KeithThompson actually, IIRC *Avada Kedavra* was first introduced in *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* which was published in 2000, while the movie *HP and the Chamber of Secrets* was released in 2002. So, even out-of-universe, this was around for like 2 years

Comment: @Valorum He pulls out his wand and incants Avada....? No he didn't. That curse wasn't invented by the time

Comment: It's only a life sentence until the revolution succeeds.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Taking yourself off the board to kill a toddler doesn't seem worthwhile

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**This is definitely out-of-character for [Lucius Malfoy](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Lucius_Malfoy).**
He has on numerous occasions shown to be:

- Calculating
- Sneaky
- Definitely not outwardly courageous or rash

He is also an extremely (if not the most) important Death Eater still alive / at large. So he would not go so far as to expose himself with such a controversial act.

That being said, there is definitely no mention or evidence of "Avada..." leading to anything other than "...Kedavra"; so it is fair to assume that he was going to use the [Killing Curse](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Killing_Curse) in the movie.

---

It is important to mention here as well that (as the OP pointed out) this is only in the film version; in the books he merely "lunges" at Harry:

> Lucius Malfoy stood frozen, staring at the elf. Then he lunged at Harry.
> “You’ve lost me my servant, boy!”
> But Dobby shouted, “You shall not harm Harry Potter!”
> There was a loud bang, and Mr. Malfoy was thrown backward.
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter Eighteen, "Dobby's Reward"</sub>

---

So why the discrepancy?

**Out-of-Universe**
Personally I feel that it was the writers' and the [actor's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Isaacs) way of adding effect to Lucius wielding his wand and dramatising the whole affair. He is extremely upset at both his diary ploy being foiled as well as losing his family's servant. Additionally, it adds strength to the effect of Dobby stopping him, with relative ease.

**In-Universe**
Lucius has a  cunning attitude as well as a strong influence both [in the Ministry](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Books/Order_of_the_Phoenix/Chapter_9) and with the [Hogwarts Governance Board](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Hogwarts_Board_of_Governors); he likely could have tried to murder Harry and then:

- **Pass the blame onto his servant, [Dobby](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Dobby)**
- **Accuse Harry of attacking him first and claim [Self-Defence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_self-defense)**

Both are viable and fit in with his character, as well as his high influence and control over members of the Ministry or the Wizengamot.

Comment: Much as I hate this phrase on SFF.SE, but "because bad writing" seems appropriate here.

Comment: @DVK Yeah, I'm loathe to add that, but it seems the best explanation given that it was a change from the novels, and not very well explained.

Comment: @DVK:  Could the creators of the film have known this?  I think we only get to learn about Lucius Malfoy at work from the last two books, which weren't yet available when that film was made.

Comment: I think no small part of it was that in book having an adult physically assault (lunge for) a child is "ok" to show, but on film it probably would have causes issues, so a wand attack would have cause less issues with censors.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Well yeah, everyone knows attempted assault is far more serious than murder.

Comment: In the book, Malfoy is on the verge of attacking Dumbledore shortly before that scene, but thinks better of it: *Lucius Malfoy stood for a moment, and Harry distinctly saw his right hand twitch as though he was longing to reach for his wand. Instead, he turned to his house-elf. ‘We’re going, Dobby!’*

Comment: @Chirlu good comparison of Book vs. Movir. Might be the "inspiration" for them putting the scene in

Comment: @Mooz: Yeah, although in that book scene, Malfoy is far more controlled. There is a huge difference between aborting the attempt after just a twitch, and actually saying the incantation until stopped by someone else. And of course, he might have wished to only hex Dumbledore.

Answer (score 20):

According to [*Harry Potter: The Wand Collection*](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter:_The_Wand_Collection) (your canon mileage may vary) Lucius did intend to kill Harry using Avada Kedavra prior to Dobby stopping the act...

> Lucius is a known practitioner of the Dark Arts with his wand, including Unforgivable Curses. He attempted to perform the Killing Curse on Harry in Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, but his once-enslaved house-elf Dobby interfered and repelled him.
>
> <sup>*Harry Potter: The Wand Collection - Lucius Malfoy*</sup>

Comment: Well done for finding a (semi-canon, at least) necro answer!

Comment: _Dislike for the films intensifies_

Answer (score 6):

Avada need not lead to Kedavra as Richard points out in the comments. J drew it from some ancient [Aramaic mystic medicinal curse](https://www.languagerealm.com/hplang/unforgivable_curses.php). The goal being to kill that which kills you.

Even if you're more into the similarity with abracadabra you'd know that it's [not the only abra](https://www.haaretz.com/2013-05-08/ty-article/word-of-the-day-abracadabra/0000017f-e08b-d38f-a57f-e6db9da50000). It will create pain rather than death being the first that comes to mind.

Indeed without question Dobby had heard the crazed wizard use it to harm people previously but he didn't respond with much more than a single [magical swift kick to the groin](https://youtu.be/6JUXPaarIbM).

Comment: The question is also asked by @Richard

Comment: According to the Wiki and numerous other internet sites, the line was improvised by Jason Isaacs and he does say “Avada”.

Answer (score 3):

I watched the movie both on TV with subtitles and DVD with subtitles. In both, the spell on screen says 'vera' and is interrupted by Dobby. I don't know if there's a canonical spell starting with that but every time I watch it, the subtitles say that. I personally don't think he'd attempt to kill Harry especially outside of Dumbledore's office and when they can check what his last spell was. Not to mention it could only be Voldemort who could kill Harry with the killing curse as he was a horcrux and the spell would bounce off Harry if done by anyone else; like when in Deathly Hallows part two Ron is suspected of using the killing curse on Nagini before Neville kills the snake and Nagini was unaffected by it.

Comment: Is there any evidence that Avada Kadavra can't kill Harry, it was only when Voldemort used it on Harry that it didn't kill him. And that's because of the soul piece in Harry (because Harry isn't actually a Horcrux). Also when does Ron use Avada Kadavra on Nagini?

Comment: Ron using the killing curse? well, that didn't happen i'm afraid.

Comment: @Edlothiad - In DH2 Ron casts a wordless green spell at the snake just before it gets beheaded.

Comment: @Valorum yeah the movie did show that (Ron cast that spell on the stairs, I remember). But Ron casting a killing curse without uttering the words? Even Voldemort hasn't been seen doing so (as far as I have seen). And by the looks of it, Ron was never such a skilled spell-caster either.

Comment: Not to mention, the killing curse simply... kills you. It doesn't behead you to do that. Any curse that cut off a snake's head would not be Avada Kadavra.

Answer (score 2):

I'm flabbergasted that there weren't more fans who support the FACT that Malfoy wasn't about to utter an Unforgivable Curse but that he was saying "Vera... " as substantiated by the Closed Captioning on both DVD and Netflix and HBO.

Seemingly all the other subtitles were correct so why so many people feed off a barely audible  half muttered curse is preposterous to me.  Am I missing something?

Obviously I have had this conversation come up within my own household, otherwise I wouldn't be here, but clearly the text say LM said, "Vera... " before being foiled by the house elf.

Is it simply everyone's need to so call stereotype Malfoy as this incredibly evil and colossally idiotic character that we hear an incantation not previously uttered and not mentioned until two installments later in GoF?

I don't think either Chris Columbus or JK Rowling would treat the single most deadly and important curse Avada Kedavra as a half spewn partially recognizable, and widely debatable flaw at the end of the movie and be done with it. Mrs. Rowling maintained creative input for all the HP films and her book fans were and are still her highest priority. Such an addition would've been blasphemous to the so called "canon" that are the books.

So by logical deducement I have to say Malfoy was incanting another spell, more likely in the Transfiguration genre than the Unforgivable kind.

Comment: *"Such an addition would've been blasphemous to the so called "cannon" that are the books"*. I mean...have you seen the movies? 'Cause they do that quite a lot. DIDJA PUT YER NAME IN THE GOBLET, HARRY!?

Comment: The films contain _plenty_ of stuff that omits or contradicts book canon (it's canon, not cannon by the way).

Comment: Closed captions are often incorrect.

Comment: This is noting more than some speculation added to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179320/53088) posted 9 months earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Malfoy temporarily lost his temper and was going to kill Harry, but only because of bad writing. That's the only thing that can explain the differences from book and movie. Otherwise I can't believe that the cool, calm, collected, powerful Lucius Malfoy would actually kill a twelve-year-old right outside of Dumbledore's office with witnesses.